# Backslash automatically getting removed from the json while reading and need to preseve the backslash - Azure Data Factory

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory, etl, transformation

Backslash from the json is getting removed after the file is processed by copy activity

I have json input file which contains the below object

**INPUT**

```
{
    "Name": "xyz",
    "DOB":"14\/09\/1995"

}
```

After i read the files and save using the copy activity backslash from the DOB is getting removed.

**Actual OUTPUT getting from Copy activity**

```
{
    "Name": "xyz",
    "DOB":"14/09/1995"

}
```

I need to preserve the backslash

**Required Output needed after copy activity**

```
{
    "Name": "xyz",
    "DOB":"14\/09\/1995"

}
```

Comment: Please read [ask]; in particular the part about providing a [mcve]. We can't really answer a question based on: 1. *somehow* read JSON 2. ???? 3. There are no escape characters.

Comment: I'm getting the output without the backslash after i read the input using the copy activity. i would like to preserve the backslash after the copy activity processed and save the file.

1) Input
2) Output which i'm getting after the copy activity
3) Required Output

Answer (score 0):

`{"Name": "xyz", "DOB":"14\\/09\\/1995" }`
i think you should use two backslashes to see one in the output , because json avoids backslashes.

Comment: Input json file is generated by the different team and we need to process in ADF. Next team need the output with backslash so we can't add double backslash to the input

Answer (score 0):

If you can not change the JSON input, you can use ADF expression for escaping the backslashes

you can use a Derived Column transformation.

Create new column with an expression that can escape the backslashes in the DOB column. You can use the replace function for this:

`replace(DOB, "/", "\\/")`